# SQL Server on database drop trigger deleting associated agent jobs

Tags: sql-server

We have databases with associated SQL agent jobs that we keep track in a table called databasename.dbo.sqlagentjobs. Some databases are demos or QA databases and get regularly deleted.

At some point it happens that the administrator forgets to delete the associated SQL Agent jobs. In this case I wanted to write a trigger on database drop like this:

```
create trigger deleteagentjobs on all server for drop_database as
begin
 declare @databasename nvarchar(100)
 declare @eventdata xml
 declare @query nvarchar(1000)

 set @eventdata = EVENTDATA()
 set @databasename = @eventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','varchar(128)')

 if object_id(@databasename +'.dbo.sqlagentjobs') is not null begin -- check if the database is a database with "our" database scheme
  set @query = N'declare c insensitive cursor for select jobname_komplett from ' + @databasename + N'.dbo.sqlagentjobs ' + 
               N'declare @jobname nvarchar(257) ' + 
               N'declare @jobid uniqueidentifier ' +
               N'open c ' +
               N'fetch next from c into @jobname ' +
               N'while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin ' +
               N' select job_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where name = @jobname ' +
               N' exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @jobid ' +
               N' fetch next from c into @jobname ' +
               N'end ' +
               N'close c ' +
               N'deallocate c '
  exec sp_sqlexec @query
 end
end
```

The issue with the trigger is that I get the following logical error message when I try to drop the database as follows:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = n'demo'
go
alter database [demo] set single_user with rollback immediate
go
drop database [demo]
```

Error message:

```
Msg 5064, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Changes to the state or options of database demo cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 3702, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
Cannot drop database demo because it is currently in use.
```

The error makes sense to me since I set the database to single user mode and try to access the database inside of the trigger.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It says a single user is connected, are you connected yourself somewhere?

Comment: select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where database_id = db_id('demo') - no results